# Switching a solution between assembly references and project references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process, fortran, projects-and-solutions

We have a .NET 4.0 solution which contains a [Fortran 95 for Windows](http://www.silverfrost.com/11/ftn95/ftn95_fortran_95_for_windows.aspx) project whose output is a managed DLL. The solution builds a Winforms app which uses this managed DLL.

The Visual Studio plugin which supports the `.ftn95p` project type is flaky at best, for example, it uses absolute paths to source code files which have to be fixed up in a pre-build script - which causes its own problems to do with project file reloading - all sorts of modal dialogues get thrown during the build, which is no fun for a developer who doesn't need to ever touch the Fortran source.

I am trying to think of ways to smooth out the process of building the solution on a clean machine.

I have built the Fortran DLL manually, and added a reference to it where required in the other projects, removed the Fortran project entirely, and everything works perfectly.

However there are some developers that will need to have the whole solution, as it is now, with the Fortran project loaded into the IDE.

I am looking for ideas on how we can better support both classes of developer:

- those who need to touch the Fortran (who will just have to continue putting up with the flaky build
- those who never need to touch the Fortran (who would benefit from never having to deal with the Fortran plugin's weirdness)

I have already considered two solutions, but there are maintenance/sync issues there. Could we leverage Build Configurations in a clever way? I can't think how, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Impressive that somebody can make a living selling tools like this.  I imagine they'll need your support dollars to keep alive, don't hesitate to spend the money to work with them in solving your problems.

Comment: there do seem to be alternatives (http://www.lahey.com/lf71/lfnet.htm)

Comment: "Visual Studio .NET 2003 is the industry standard in development environments" :-(